# ArgumentError while using Delegator class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, model, rake

I checked other questions also  but couldn't fix this error:

I am calling my model class from a rake task.

**authority_delegator.rake**

```
namespace :authority_delegator do
 desc "send delegation"
 task delegator: :environment do
  delegator = Delegator.new
 end

end
```

**deligation.rb**

```
require 'csv'
class Delegator
 @@file_path = "/Users/raj.sharma/Desktop/deligation.csv"

 def read_csv
  delegations = CSV.read(@@file_path)
 end
end
```

**error log**

[image]

How to fix this error? Sorry I am new to rails.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to fix wrong argument error?

Comment: The stack trace shows `Delegator.new` is not related to `deligation.rb` it is comes from someother place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Delegator` is a bad name for your class, don't use it, it's a [`built-in ruby class`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html).

> provides three different ways to delegate method calls to an object.

<sub>Also the file of lib must have the same name as class/module in this file. Check this out [Love Your lib Directory](https://dockyard.com/blog/ruby/2012/02/14/love-your-lib-directory)</sub>